# how to update canvas "progress" bar?

Tags: python, tkinter

i can't figure it out. I tried also `after()` in the loop. The goal is, to have progress bar by using canvas (and updating label). The Problem is, that the whole window spawns after the "loop".

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
root.geometry("350x350")
root.maxsize(350,350)
root.minsize(350, 350)
root.attributes("-transparentcolor", "red")

can = Canvas(root, bg="red", highlightthickness=0)
can.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

ext = 3.59
for x in range(100):
    can.create_arc(10, 10, 340, 340, extent=ext, fill="#a7bee6", width=0)
    #time.sleep(0.1)
    ext += 3.59
can.create_oval(30, 30, 320, 320, fill="red", width=0)
can.create_oval(50, 50, 300, 300, fill="#1f1f1f", width=0)

lbl = Label(can, bg="#1f1f1f", fg="#a7bee6", text="%", font=("Consolas", 30))
lbl.pack(pady=150)

for x in range(101):
    lbl.configure(text=f"{x}%")
    time.sleep(0.1)


mainloop()
```

Comment: While the code execution is inside the for loop, the window isn't going to update.

Comment: Also you know that tkinter has a [progressbar widget](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Progressbar.html).

Comment: yes i know the progress bar. But I can't find any `oval` settings (to put this status bar around the created oval) , so i tried to make this with canvas. I also know how to do it with frames, when you have 10 of them and one frame appear e.g. as "green". But that isn't the point right now.

Comment: Use `after(ms,func,*args)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fairly achievable using `after(ms,func)`, just remove all your code that does the increment from the main block and move it inside a function and just use `after`, like:

```
count = 0
def progress():
    global ext, count
    if count < 100: # Same as doing 100 loops
        can.create_arc(10, 10, 340, 340, extent=ext, fill="#a7bee6", width=0)
        ext += 3.59
        count += 1
        lbl.configure(text=f"{count}%") # Update label 
        root.after(100,progress) # Same as time.sleep(0.1)

progress() # Call the function initially
```

When you use `time.sleep()` it blocks the `mainloop` from being able to process or update events and hence the GUI remains frozen till `time.sleep()` or any other loops are done.

---

Though I am not going over the functionality of the progressbar, it seems even at the end there is a bit of place left for it to cover to show 100 percentage of the circle. I think incrementing `ext` by 3.60 will fix it(`ext+=3.60`).